# Simple Question: Matplotlib drawing multiple 2d lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, 2d, line

I want to draw multiple 2D lines in Mat-Plot-Lib, but want to animate them onto a plot.
In other words, I want one line to appear, then another, then another, and so on...
Currently, I have the following:

```
for line in lines:
 y = line
 plt.plot(x,y,'-r')
 plt.grid()
 plt.show()
 time.sleep(1)
```

However, what ends up happening is that I get a bunch of different plots, each plotting the next line. I need all of these lines to appear on the same graph, one after another.
How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you can stack the individual images in a list and create a gif from it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-an-animated-gif-using-python-matplotlib/

Comment: Hmm... Okay, I will try that. If you think of a better way do let me know

Comment: Don't do what yoyoog suggests. Instead, get familiar with [matplotlib OOP](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) - create figure and axis objects outside the loop, then add your line plots to the axis object within the loop with `plt.pause(1)` to allow matplotlib to update the figure.

Comment: I looked into it. Could you maybe provide some sample code where you display one line and then a bit later you display another?

Comment: I posted some example code below that I will delete when you have seen it. There are various similar questions on SO, but I cannot find them right now.

Answer (score 0):

plt.show after the lines are drawn:

```
for line in lines:
 y = line
 plt.plot(x,y,'-r')
 plt.grid()
 time.sleep(1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This will not work because then this is not animated, it just plots all the lines.